# Leave missing values blank when creating a new column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a description column and I am trying to parse out measurements from text in that column.

```
df['measurements'] = [re.findall('\S+\scm', i) + re.findall('\S+cm', i) for i in df['description'] if i is not None]
#...
```

Some of the rows in the description column are empty so the code above gives me a ValueError because the length of values doesn't match the length of the index. How do I append a filler value like NaN if the row is empty so that the length of the values matches the length of the index and the new measurements column can be made?

The output would look similar to this:
eg.

```
description                       measurements 
blabla 32cm x 24cm x 12cm blabla  ['32cm', '24cm', '12cm']
NaN                               NaN
18cm x 15cm x 10cm blablabla      ['18cm', '15cm', '10cm']
NaN                               NaN
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired output?

Comment: I change output by sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) what works with `None`s perfectly - it return `NaN` in output:

```
df['measurements'] = df['description'].str.findall('\S+\scm') + 
                     df['description'].str.findall('\S+cm')
```

And if need replace `None`s to empty lists simpliest is use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
des = df['description'].fillna('')
df['measurements'] = des.str.findall('\S+\scm') + des.str.findall('\S+cm')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description':['blabla 32cm x 24cm x 12cm blabla',np.nan,
                                  '18cm x 15cm x 10cm blablabla',np.nan]})
print (df)
                        description
0  blabla 32cm x 24cm x 12cm blabla
1                               NaN
2      18cm x 15cm x 10cm blablabla
3                               NaN

df['measurements'] = df['description'].str.findall('\S+\scm') + \
                     df['description'].str.findall('\S+cm')

print (df)
                        description        measurements
0  blabla 32cm x 24cm x 12cm blabla  [32cm, 24cm, 12cm]
1                               NaN                 NaN
2      18cm x 15cm x 10cm blablabla  [18cm, 15cm, 10cm]
3                               NaN                 NaN
```

---

```
des = df['description'].fillna('')
df['measurements'] = des.str.findall('\S+\scm') + des.str.findall('\S+cm')
print (df)
                        description        measurements
0  blabla 32cm x 24cm x 12cm blabla  [32cm, 24cm, 12cm]
1                               NaN                  []
2      18cm x 15cm x 10cm blablabla  [18cm, 15cm, 10cm]
3                               NaN                  []
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot that you could just fillna before running the search. I was just using dropna but realized the dropped rows could still be useful later on.

Comment: Yes, I think better is use `fillna` and get `[]` instead `NaN`s if need process data later. Becuae if in columns are lists with scalar (`NaN`s) some function can failed.